# Best Practices for client identification and encryption with logstash TCP/UPD input

Tags: ssl, encryption, logstash

I have a system of several clients which collect data and send it to the server. On the server, I put logstash to listen on a specific port for TCP or UPD.
I have two requirements: encryption of the data and a mechanism to identify the clients.

What are the best practices for these two requirements?

I guess the using TLS I can encrypt the data, but it does not identify the client for me. Can I use Two-Way-TLS in Logstash tcp/udp input? If yes --> how?
If no --> What are the alternatives?

Thanks,
H Guy

Comment: Your questions are not unreasonable, but they are in my opinion too broad for the Q&A format in stackoverflow. I can think of several questions to ask you to clarify your requirements, but that only reinforces my belief that the question is too broad.

Comment: OK. I will try to narrow the question: Does logstash TCP input support Two-Way-TLS? I couldn't find any solution for this in logstash documentation. If no, is there any other alternative?